# Nesting Python dictionaries error

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

ERROR:

```
KeyError: 13
```

What I am trying to accomplish is create a dictionary of dictionaries like so:

```
dict {
 "a" => {
       5 => 15,     
       6 => 16
     },
 "b" => {
       1 => 15
     }
}

def ProcessFile(self, fileName):
    fileStream = open(fileName, "rt")
    # parse each line of the file
    for line in fileStream.readlines():
        # tokenize the line
        line_tokens = line.split("\t")
        distance = self.EditDistance(line_tokens[3], line_tokens[4])
        lang = line_tokens[0]
        try:
            if lang in self.langStatistics:
                self.langStatistics[lang][distance]+=1
            else:
                # if the key has not been used before, create a new dictionary
ERROR   ---->   self.langStatistics[lang] = defaultdict();
                self.langStatistics[lang][distance] = 1
        except Exception,e:
            print(e)
            sys.exit(2)
```

`self.langStatistics` is initialized like so:

```
self.langStatistics = defaultdict(dict);
```

The ProcessFile method is throwing an error at `self.langStatistics[lang] = defaultdict();`

and I am not sure why. I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Which error? Please post the traceback...

Comment: Other than the fact that that isn't valid python for a dictionary, what's the traceback?

Comment: I just edited my answer with the Error. Not sure why people would simply downvote so quickly.

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov Quick downvote is likely for these reasons: your questions started with plain wrong sample of dict (using reserved `dict` and completely ignoring Pyhton syntax of dictionary) and for you did not provide the error trace.
Do not hesitate to provide error trace in full detail, it makes answering much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined `self.langStatistics` as a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) with `dict` values. But then, you are trying to instanciate a key with a `defaultdict`, which is not the same than a `dict`!

You need to either use `self.langStatistics = defaultdict(defaultdict)` or `self.langStatistics[lang] = {}`. Or **even simpler**: do not include this line, it is done automatically when you are trying to access to an element the first time.

```
>>> a = defaultdict(defaultdict)
>>> a['fr']['lang'] = 'abc'
>>> a['fr']
defaultdict(None, {'lang': 'abc'})
>>> a['en']
defaultdict(None, {})
```

Comment: Side note: **please**, remove these semi colons in Python. They are not mandatory.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first python script so I am still learning new things. Appreciate the help.